# Optimizing the mysql query - Avoid creation of temporary table?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

This is the query that I am using on tables : `products`, `reviews`, `replies`, `review_images`.

### Query :

```
SELECT products.id, reviews.*,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT_WS('~',replies.reply, replies.time)) AS Replies,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT_WS('~',review_images.image_title, review_images.image_location)) AS ReviewImages
FROM products
LEFT JOIN reviews on products.id = reviews.product_id
LEFT JOIN replies on reviews.id = replies.review_id
LEFT JOIN review_images on reviews.id = review_images.review_id
WHERE products.id = 1
GROUP BY products.id, reviews.id;
```

---

### **Schema** :

**Products :**

```
id  |  name  |  product_details....
```

**Reviews :**

```
id  |  product_id  |  username  |  review  |  time  | ...
```

**Replies :**

```
id  |  review_id   |  username  |  reply  |  time  | ...
```

**Review Images :**

```
id  |  review_id  |  image_title  |  image_location  | ...
```

---

### **Indexes**:

**Products :**

PRIMARY KEY - id

**Reviews :**

PRIMARY KEY - id

FOREIGN KEY - product_id (id IN products table)

FOREIGN KEY - username (username IN users table)

**Replies :**

PRIMARY KEY - id

FOREIGN KEY - review_id (id IN reviews table)

FOREIGN KEY - username (username IN users table)

**Review Images :**

PRIMARY KEY - id

FOREIGN KEY - review_id (id IN reviews table)

---

### Explain Query :

**id**  |  **select_type**  |  **table**  |  **type**  |  **possible_keys**  |  **rows**  |  **extra**

1  |  SIMPLE  |  products  |  index  |  null  |  1  |  Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort

1  |  SIMPLE  |  reviews  |  ALL  |  product_id  |  4  |  Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)

1  |  SIMPLE  |  replies  |  ref  |  review_id  |  1  |  Null

1  |  SIMPLE  |  review_images  |  ALL  |  review_id  |  5  |  Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)

I don't know what is wrong here, that it needs to use filesort and create a temporary table?

**Here are few Profiling results :**

Opening Tables  140 µs

Init    139 µs

System Lock     34 µs

Optimizing  21 µs

Statistics  106 µs

Preparing   146 µs

Creating Tmp Table  13.6 ms

Sorting Result  27 µs

Executing   11 µs

Sending Data    11.6 ms

Creating Sort Index     1.4 ms

End     89 µs

Removing Tmp Table  8.9 ms

End     34 µs

Query End   25 µs

Closing Tables  66 µs

Freeing Items   41 µs

Removing Tmp Table  1.4 ms

Freeing Items   46 µs

Removing Tmp Table  1.2 ms

Freeing Items   203 µs

Cleaning Up     55 µs

---

As from the Explain and Profiling results, it is clear that temporary table is created to produce the results. How can I optimize this query to get similar results and better performance and avoid the creation of temporary table?

Help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

### Create Tables

```
CREATE TABLE `products` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 `description` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 `items` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `price` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB

CREATE TABLE `reviews` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `username` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
 `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `review` text NOT NULL,
 `time` datetime NOT NULL,
 `ratings` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `product_id` (`product_id`),
 KEY `username` (`username`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB

CREATE TABLE `replies` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `review_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `username` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
 `reply` text NOT NULL,
 `time` datetime NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `review_id` (`review_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB

CREATE TABLE `review_images` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `review_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `image_title` text NOT NULL,
 `image_location` text NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `review_id` (`review_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

**EDIT**:

I simplified the query above and now it does not create temporary tables. The only reason as mentioned by @Bill Karwin was that I was using `GROUP BY` on second table in the joins.

Simplified query :

```
SELECT reviews. * ,
GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT CONCAT_WS( '~', replies.reply, replies.time ) ) AS Replies,
GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT CONCAT_WS( '~', review_images.image_title, review_images.image_location ) ) AS ReviewImages
FROM reviews
LEFT JOIN replies ON reviews.id = replies.review_id
LEFT JOIN review_images ON reviews.id = review_images.review_id
WHERE reviews.product_id = 1
GROUP BY reviews.id
```

Now the **PROBLEM** that I'm facing is :

Because I'm using GROUP_CONCAT, there is a limit to the data it can hold which is in the variable `GROUP_CONCAT_MAX_LEN`, so as I'm concatenating the replies given by the users, it could go very very long and can possibly exceed the memory defined. I know I can change the value of `GROUP_CONCAT_MAX_LEN` for current session, but still there is a limitation to it that at some point in time, the query may fail or unable to fetch complete results.

How can I modify my query so as not to use `GROUP_CONCAT` and still get results expected.

**POSSIBLE SOLUTION :**

Simply using LEFT JOINS, which creates duplicate rows for every new result in the last column and which makes it hard to traverse in `php`? Any suggestions?

I see this question is not getting enough response from SO members. But I've been looking for the solution and searching about concepts since last to last week. Still no luck. Hope some of you PROs can help me out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't avoid creating a temporary table when your GROUP BY clause references columns from two different tables.

The only way to avoid the temporary table in this query is to store a denormalized version of the data in one table, and index the two columns you're grouping by.

---

Another way you can simplify and get results in a format that's easier to work with in PHP is to do multiple queries, without GROUP BY.

First get the reviews. Example is in PHP & PDO, but the principle applies to any language.

```
$review_stmt = $pdo->query("
    SELECT reviews.*,
    FROM reviews
    WHERE reviews.product_id = 1");
```

Arrange them in an associative array keyed by the review_id.

```
$reviews = array();
while ($row => $review_stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $reviews[$row['d']] = $row;
}
```

Then get the replies and append them to an array using the key 'replies'. Use INNER JOIN instead of LEFT JOIN, because it's okay if there are no replies.

```
$reply_stmt = $pdo->query("
    SELECT replies.*
    FROM reviews
    INNER JOIN replies ON reviews.id = replies.review_id
    WHERE reviews.product_id = 1");
while ($row = $reply_stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $reviews[$row['review_id']]['replies'][] = $row; 
}
```

And do the same for review_images.

```
$reply_stmt = $pdo->query("
    SELECT review_images.*
    FROM reviews
    INNER JOIN review_images ON reviews.id = review_images.review_id
    WHERE reviews.product_id = 1");
while ($row = $reply_stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $reviews[$row['review_id']]['review_images'][] = $row; 
}
```

The end result is an array of reviews, which contains elements which are nested arrays for related replies and images respectively.

The efficiency of running simpler queries can make up for the extra work of running three queries. Plus you don't have to write code to `explode()` the group-concatted strings.

Comment: I've read that in Docs, but is there any other way to achieve the similar results provided by this query?

Comment: On normally joining the tables without GROUP_CONCAT and GROUP_BY, I am getting desirable results. No temporary tables are created and no file sort is applied. But the result expands to many rows containing repeating data for different values in the last joined table. I could traverse through that in PHP but was thinking mysql might provide any better way to do that. Any thoughts?

Comment: Also, GROUP_CONCAT is dependent upon `GROUP_CONCAT_MAX_LEN`, which may cause issues on concatenating long reviews and replies. So, I'm confused. @Bill Karwin

Comment: So, what are you suggesting would be a better way to approach this particular problem? How would you have done it as you are quite experienced and I want to learn.

Comment: Please see my question's edited part. I'll be glad if you help.

Comment: Thank you. I understand now that we can use simpler queries when the complex ones are not so efficient.